# Sanitized queries in pyodbc returns only the field name

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

When I query my SQL server with pyodbc, I get only the name of the field I requested (instead of the values itself).

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT ? FROM [Projects]', '[ProjectNo]')
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

This prints the following:

```
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
('[ProjectNo]', )
```

The number of lines is equal to the number of rows in the Projects table. I have the same issue when the second argument in cursor.execute is "[ProjectNo]", "ProjectNo", or even "blahblahblahblah"; each row only gives the requested field's name.

I do not have this problem if I use only one argument in cursor.execute:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT [ProjectNo] FROM [Projects]')
```

This will return what I expect it to.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't use parameters for the db objects (columns, tables..). Use it for values only.

Comment: @Serg Aha, of course. I remembered having this problem before, and that the answer was obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Serg answered in a comment:

Column names can't be a variable parameter in a constructed query/statement. Only *values* can be a parameter.

Comment: Can you show some code for your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this,

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT {} FROM [Projects]".format('[ProjectNo]'))
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```